# does a di box can run a condenser microphone?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording

I'm planning on buying a DI box, essentially for bass. But I'm thinking getting latter a microphone, and i was asking myself if an active DI can work with a condenser microphone, without any pre-amp.
I don't really know a lot of thing on the record procedure for microphone, so it's may be a dumb question, but explication would be really nice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the purpose of a DI box is to *act like a microphone* (balanced XLR output, low impedance, Galvanic decoupling) when you're not really using a microphone. When you are using a microphone, you don't need a DI either, because you already have a standard mic signal.

What you do need, however, is a *mic preamp* (or, some mixer/interface with built-in mic preamps), with phantom power if you want to use a condenser mic. But actually, you need that for a DI box as well – at least for an active DI. Either that, or change batteries all the time.

So, no, a DI box can not “run a condenser microphone”. Some instrument preamps (which are normally able to act as a DI, too) have mic inputs as well, but that's an extra feature then.